# Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in JMeter

Tags: websocket, socket.io, jmeter

I am getting the **following error**, after trying to run JMeter on **the console**. It is working fine in **GUI mode**.

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/Users/omaroof/Desktop/Mywork/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/SocketTestingCoApp.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler : JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler
--
```

Comment: Is the **JMeter instance** same for both **console** mode and **GUI** mode?

Comment: Yes its same. Ay idea what could go wrong?

Comment: Hi got it working I was using the wrong instance of Jmeter. Always make sure you using the write one.

Comment: So, this was the issue for not using the same JMeter instance for GUI and Non-GUI mode.

Comment: Yeh, as their were two instances of Jmeter on my machine. and one did not had websockets :)